# Проблема с редактированием (SpringMVC )

Tags: java, spring, java-ee, spring-mvc

Я написал проект который позволяет добавлять студента в БД (фио и аватарку) и редактировать имя и фамилию. Но я решил что будет правильней если можно будет редактировать аватарку(заново можно будет добавлять фотку)

Я написал код но он выдает ошибку 405, можете посмотреть может где-то что-то неправильно написал

Student Controller

```
package adil.java.schoolmaven.controller;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.List;
import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import adil.java.schoolmaven.entity.Student;
import adil.java.schoolmaven.service.StudentService;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
public class StudentController {

    @Value("${storage.location}")
    private String storageLocation;

    @Autowired
    private ServletContext servletContext;

    // Constructor based Dependency Injection
    private StudentService studentService;

    public StudentController() {

    }

    @Autowired
    public StudentController(StudentService studentService) {
        this.studentService = studentService;
    }


    @RequestMapping(value = {"/", "/index"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView hello() {
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView();
        mv.setViewName("index");
        return mv;
    }

    // Get All Users
    @RequestMapping(value = "/allStudents", method = {RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST})
    public ModelAndView displayAllUser() {
        System.out.println("User Page Requested : All Students");
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView();
        List<Student> studentList = studentService.getAllStudents();
        mv.addObject("studentList", studentList);
        mv.setViewName("allStudents");
        return mv;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/addStudent", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView displayNewUserForm() {
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("addStudent");
        mv.addObject("headerMessage", "Add Student Details");
        mv.addObject("student", new Student());
        return mv;
    }

    @PostMapping(value = "/addStudent")
    public String saveNewStudent(@RequestParam("name") String name,
            @RequestParam("surname") String surname,
            @RequestParam("avatar") MultipartFile file)
            throws IOException {

        if (file != null && !file.isEmpty()) {
            Student student = new Student();
            student.setSurname(surname);
            student.setName(name);
            student.setAvatar(file.getOriginalFilename());
            file.transferTo(new File(storageLocation + "/" + file.getOriginalFilename()));
            studentService.saveStudent(student);
        }
        return "redirect:/allStudents";
    }



    @RequestMapping(value = "/editStudent/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView displayEditUserForm(@PathVariable Long id) {
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("/editStudent");
        Student student = studentService.getStudentById(id);
        mv.addObject("headerMessage", "Редактирование студента");
        mv.addObject("student", student);
        return mv;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/editStudent", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView saveEditedUser(@ModelAttribute Student student, BindingResult result) {
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("redirect:/allStudents");

        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            System.out.println(result.toString());
            return new ModelAndView("error");
        }
        Student targetStudent = studentService.getStudentById(student.getId());

        if (student.getName() != null && !student.getName().equals(targetStudent.getName())) {

            targetStudent.setName(student.getName());

        }

        if (student.getSurname() != null && !student.getSurname().equals(targetStudent.getSurname())) {

            targetStudent.setSurname(student.getSurname());

        }

        if (student.getAvatar() != null && !student.getAvatar().equals(targetStudent.getAvatar())) {

            targetStudent.setAvatar(student.getAvatar());

        }

        boolean isSaved = studentService.saveStudent(targetStudent);

        if (!isSaved) {

            return new ModelAndView("error");
        }

        return mv;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/deleteStudent/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView deleteUserById(@PathVariable Long id) {
        boolean isDeleted = studentService.deleteStudentById(id);
        System.out.println("Студент удален: " + isDeleted);
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("redirect:/allStudents");
        return mv;

    }


}
```

Edit Student JSP

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<title>Home</title>
</head>
<body>
    <center>
    <h1>${headerMessage}</h1>

        <form:form method="POST" action="editStudent" modelAttribute="student">

            <form:hidden path="id" /> 
             <table>
                <tr>
                    <td><form:label path="name">Имя</form:label></td>
                    <td><form:input path="name"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><form:label path="surname">Фамилия</form:label></td>
                    <td><form:input path="surname"/></td>
                </tr>
                <td><label path="Avatar">Фотография:</label></td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="file" name="avatar"/>
                    </td>

                <tr>
                   <td><input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Изменить"></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form:form>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Вот такая ошибка, странно то что в журнале томката нету никакой ошибки
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: > он выдает ошибку 405: добавьте полный стек ошибки в вопрос.

Comment: Добавил журнал томкат

Comment: правил недавно еще раз

Comment: то что вы скинули, там нет информации об ошибке. А без этого не понятно.

Comment: Ошибку не выводит вот сейчас скину картинку

Comment: а почему у вас в `URL` два раза `/editStudents`?

Comment: Блин не заметил, из-за этого может быть такая ошибка?

Comment: Вам не кажется что у вас URL не правильный?

Comment: У меня в контроллере все правильно прописано же? там вроде url все правильно задал

Comment: Где тут возвращает jsp?